# Переопределение константы плагина wordpress. Как реализовать?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть плагин: **Login reCAPTCHA** (WP Login reCAPTCHA)

У него достаточно скудные настройки, в которых невозможно задать свой IP адрес, для того, чтобы не выводить CAPTCHA для себя.

В коде плагина (в файле wp-login-recaptcha.php) есть константа: `define('XRVEL_LOGIN_RECAPTCHA_ENABLED', true);`
Эта константа включает по умолчанию плагин для всех

Если в коде плагина (в файле wp-login-recaptcha.php) задать дополнительное условие, то мы сможем решить вопрос отображения CAPTCHA для своего IP адреса.

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '11.22.33.44') {
    define('XRVEL_LOGIN_RECAPTCHA_ENABLED', false);
} else {
    define('XRVEL_LOGIN_RECAPTCHA_ENABLED', true);
};
```

Все эти манипуляции производятся в файле плагина, и при обновлении они будут утеряны.

Вопрос: Возможно ли как-то переопределить константу отдельного плагина, так, чтобы при обновлении плагина не терялись внесённые изменения?

Есть решение, добавить этот код в самое начало файла wp-config.php.

Да, в этом случае всё работает, но правильное ли это решение?

Можно ли как-то более изящно решить проблему (к примеру через файл functions.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, можно. В WordPress все построено на хуках. Ваш код выполнится в ходе инициализации WordPress, но после загрузки всех плагинов.

```
add_action('init', 'my_recaptcha');
function my_recaptcha() {
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '11.22.33.44') {
        remove_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'xrvel_login_recaptcha_login_enqueue_script');
        remove_action('login_form','xrvel_login_recaptcha_form');
        remove_action('wp_authenticate', 'xrvel_login_recaptcha_process', 1);
    };
}
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что этот код добавляется в файл functions.php находящийся в директории активной темы? Попробовал этот способ, хук к сожалению не срабатывает.

Comment: да, правильно. в конец function.php. ОК, поставлю плагин сейчас, посмотрю.

Comment: Да, перепроверил. Если добавлять и в начало и в конец functions.php, хук не срабатывает. WP актуальной версии.

Comment: если в файле wp-config.php сделать вот так, то работает:

`if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '11.22.33.44') {define('XRVEL_LOGIN_RECAPTCHA_ENABLED', false);}else{define('XRVEL_LOGIN_RECAPTCHA_ENABLED', true);};`

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

а вот так уже не работает:

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

`if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '11.22.33.44') {define('XRVEL_LOGIN_RECAPTCHA_ENABLED', false);}else{define('XRVEL_LOGIN_RECAPTCHA_ENABLED', true);};`

т.е. после включения wp-settings.php данный приём уже не работает.

Comment: Я исправил ответ. Посмотрел код плагина - как он использует константу. Если она определена, то в момент загрузки плагина он добавляет действия, которые и являются функционалом. Эти действия нужно отменить, если мы заходим со своего ip.

Comment: Да, всё сработало. Спасибо большое за помощь. В любом случае, по видимому необходимо отменять add_action в том или ином плагине. Понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: Все зависит от внутреннего устройства конкретного плагина...